# Difference in default "ls" and execvp "ls" call

Tags: command-line, ls

I called "ls" command using the execvp system call from inside a c file. But there seems to be a slight difference.

[image]

The exe files in the default ls call are highlighted green But not in my own execvp ls call. Am I missing something?

This is the piece of code that is calling ls.

```
else if (rc == 0) 
{ 
    // child (new process)
    printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    char *myargs[2];
    myargs[0] = strdup("ls");
    // program: "wc" (word count)
    myargs[1] = NULL;//strdup("p3.c"); // argument: file to count
    //myargs[2] = NULL;
    // marks end of array
    execvp(myargs[0], myargs); // runs word count
    printf("this shouldn’t print out");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls` in your shell is an alias to `ls --color=auto`:

```
$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

If you want the colouring in `ls` output, use the `--color` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was helpful. I can't accept the answer within another 8 minutes. So just a little longer :p

Comment: In general, run `type <name-of-command>` to see what exactly you're running. That should help you catch discrepancies sooner.